# How to know function name inside helm

Tags: emacs, helm

I just installed `helm` in Emacs.

It works fine, but I want to change some key bindings.

For example, `Go to precedent level` inside `find-file` is binding with `C-l`.
I want to rebind it with `C-w`.

I can't call `describe-key` because it is inside mini buffer.
How do I know which function is called when a specified key is hit with `helm-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

Use describe keymap and look at ones starting with helm. Look at helm- prefixed function. What you want to do is

```
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<backspace>") 'helm-find-files-up-one-level)
```

Just replace  with the key sequence you want.

Comment: What do you mean with `describe keymap`? I don't find the command. How can I use it?

Comment: Sorry, you're right this is an add-on : install help-fns+ to obtain this "describe-keymap" command.Otherwise, you can still describe-variable and select helm-find-files-map but this will not be pretty (unconvenient).